# How to use yarn to install bootstrap 4 - libsass libraries

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, libsass, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use yarn for my latest project. How to install bootstrap 4 - libsass libraries using yarn

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Attention:

I just realized a difference between the installations with `npm install` and `yarn`.

Here are the two commands I used:

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --dev
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 --save-dev
```

The correct/current version of bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 contains this file:

```
/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_tags.scss
```

Installed with npm, this file exists as expected. But installed via yarn, this file is missing. Even if changing `bootstrap@^4.0.0-alpha.6` to `bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6` in `package.json` didn't fix this issue.

Comment: actually see the last version at the github page https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases

Comment: Is bootstrap intended to be a development dependency (`--dev`)? The resources are needed at runtime.

Comment: @rgov I would say no because the stylings need to be there in production mode as well

Answer (score 6):

```
yarn add bootstrap@4
```

installs the latest bootstrap 4 version (4.6.0 at aug/'21)

---

And you can always use

```
yarn add your_package@^
```

To view all the versions that are available

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
yarn add gulp-sass --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the most current installation instructions, see github repo:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

As of the time of this posting, instructions for installing the latest beta version of Bootstrap v4 via yarn is:

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 is now in beta, so you can do the following:

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
```

Answer (score -1):

here in this https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```